# How to filter slow query using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to get slow queries (secs_running >= 5s) via pymongo. I know how to list currentOp:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://<IP>:<Port>')
db = client.admin
op_list = db.command("currentOp")
```

How can I execute the below mongo query from pymongo?

```
db.currentOP({"secs_running":{"$gte":5}})
```

I have tryed to execute the below code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
op_list = db.command("currentOp",{'secs_running':{'$gte':5}})
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, the sytnax you need is:

```
op_list = db.command({'currentOp': True, 'secs_running': {'$gte': 5}})
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/currentOp/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.currentOp